# Deserialize istream into thrust::host_vector?

Tags: c++, thrust

I don't use std streams too often so I was curious how one would deserialize an istream pointer as a vector of DataStruct [POD] in a thrust::host_vector ?

```
int numberOfDataStructs;
std::istream* bufferToDeserialize;
thrust::host_vector<DataStruct> deserializedVector;

// Copy istream into vector ?
```

Without thrust and a normal pointer, I would malloc, and then memcpy. I am not sure what the equivalent is in the thrust library ?

Comment: How was the data written to the file?  Was it binary or formatted?

Comment: The istream comes from MySql as returned in a sql::ResultSet (getBlob), it was sent to Mysql by vectorToSave.data() as a char* sterambuf using the setBlob function of mysql connector